# Я получаю файл от пользователя и сохраняю его в глобальный dict,а после обработки нескольких условий хочу записать этот файл в БД,но вылетает ошибка

Tags: django, django-orm

вот файл models.py
`class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/avatars',default='../static/img/logo.svg',null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)`

вот файл views.py

---

```
    if CustomUser.objects.filter(username = request.POST.get('login')).exists():
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Пользователь уже существует!')
        return redirect('/student/register')

    else:
         newUserInfo['username'] = request.POST.get('login')
         newUserInfo['first_name'] = request.POST.get('first_name')
         newUserInfo['last_name'] = request.POST.get('last_name')
         newUserInfo['email'] = request.POST.get('email')
         newUserInfo['password'] = request.POST.get('password')
         if 'avatar' in request.FILES:

            newUserInfo['avatar'] = request.FILES['avatar']
         else:
             newUserInfo['avatar'] = 0
         chars = '+-/abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
         code = ''
         length = random.randint(5,8)
         for i in range(length):
            code += random.choice(chars)

         newUserInfo['code'] = code
         newUserInfo['leftData'] = True
         return redirect('/student/verification')

if request.method == 'GET' and newUserInfo.get('leftData') == True:

    name = newUserInfo.get('first_name')
    code = newUserInfo.get('code')
    email = newUserInfo.get('email')

    html_message = render_to_string('email.html',{'name':name,'code':code})
    plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
    mail.send_mail('Верификация пользователя',plain_message,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,[email],html_message=html_message)

    return render(request,'code_register.html',{'email':newUserInfo.get('email')})
elif newUserInfo.get('leftData') == False:
    return redirect('/student/register')

if request.method == 'POST':
    email_code = request.POST.get('email_code')

    if email_code == newUserInfo.get('code'):
        messages.add_message(request,messages.ERROR,'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!')

        user = CustomUser()
        user.username = newUserInfo.get('username')
        user.first_name = newUserInfo.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = newUserInfo.get('last_name')
        user.email = newUserInfo.get('email')
        user.set_password(newUserInfo.get('password'))


        if newUserInfo.get('avatar') != 0:

            user.avatar = newUserInfo['avatar'].chunks()

        user.save()

        login(request,user)

        newUserInfo = {
            'leftData':False
        }

        return redirect('/student/page')
    else:
        messages.add_message(request,messages.ERROR,'Код неверен!')
        return redirect('/student/register')
```

`

Comment: Давайте начнем с того, какая ошибка и на какой строке

Comment: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: user.avatar = newUserInfo['avatar'] эта строка

Comment: Кто вас научил так "записывать"?

Comment: И кстати глобальные переменные - сами по себе плохая идея, а так как в проде Django запускается в нескольких процессах, обрабатывающих запросы без какого-либо порядка, вы поимеете проблем с вашим алгоритмом.